# Is RoboGuice wiki obsolete ? setBaseApplicationInjector does not exist?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

I am trying to use the last version to date (3.0.1) of `RoboGuice` on my new Android application using Android Studio 1.5 (stable).

Long ago, I dealt with Guice & RoboGuice but I took on some reading on how to use Roboguice with new improvements & features it got since.

The point here is that I want to use a **custom module** for **custom bindings**.

In my specific case I have a `SoundManager` class that provides tools to play multiple audio tracks at will with an internal pool of `MediaPlayer`. The main constructor takes the `applicationContext` that will be used to create new `MediaPlayer`. Furthermore this class ought to be a singleton :

1. If a track is to be played throughout the entire application, the `SoundManager` cannot be destroyed / recreated ;
2. One pool of `MediaPlayer` is enough, much like a `ExecutorPool`. It ought to be re-used whenever necessary for better resources management.

So I did the following :

1. Creating an interface exposing the default behavior of my `SoundManager` : play, stop, resume, release etc... ;
2. Implementing this interface in a fully working class ;
3. Creating a `Module` extending `com.google.inject.AbstractModule` with the following code :

> @Override
>           protected void configure() {
>               bind(SoundManagerInterface.class).to(SoundManager.class).asEagerSingleton();
>           }

Now the whole point of this SO post :

where did `RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector()` go ?? All articles I read with modules examples, the most recent as early as 2014, expose the same method : creating an Application class extending `android.app.Application` and in the `onCreate()` method, use `RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector()`. But it does not exist ! The only available methods I have are :

- `RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector()`
- `RoboGuice.destroyInjector()`
- `RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule()`
- `RoboGuice.overrideApplicationInjector()`
- `RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases()`
- `RoboGuice.injectMembers()`

In my case I used `getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector()` because it seemed to be the closest to `setBaseApplicationInjector()` and finally went on testing my code.

Suprise, it worked ! My `SoundManager` is properly created and the applicationContext is somehow injected (from where, I do not know, but I hope it's not the calling `Activity` or else I am done for leaking memory...) and audio tracks are indeed played.

But is the instance of my `SoundManager` that of a singleton ? No it is not. I tried injecting 3 of those and there are all differents object as the debugger is showing...

So what am I doing wrong ?

This link : https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Advanced-Custom-Bindings#register-the-module-with-roboguice cannot be reproduced in my code :/

Answer (score 0):

The correct setup code is as per the [wiki](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Advanced-Custom-Bindings) :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(this, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this),
                new SoundManagerModule(),
                );
    }
}
```

From your use case (persistence throughout the entire activity, start/stop etc), it sounds like you want to create a [`RoboService`](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-Injected-Service-and-BroadcastReceiver) and inject the `SoundManager` into that. Please see the documentation on [Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Merely creating a `Singleton` will not allow you to completely avoid standard Android architecture patterns.

Comment: thanks for your input but I managed to use RoboGuice 3 without having to write anything the Application class and it works. Don't know how, but it works.